# delete duplicated record and reserve only one record using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using the SQL below to delete duplicated record and reserve only min(id) record

```
delete from admin_sync_user 
where login_name in
(select login_name from 
(select login_name from admin_sync_user group by login_name having count(login_name) > 1) as a)
and id not in
(select login_name from
(select min(id) from admin_sync_user group by login_name having count(login_name) > 1) as b)
```

But my problem is: the SQL only execute like below and doesn't use the second condition. I am using MYSQL database. Does anyone know what is the problem with MySQL above and how to modify it?

```
  delete from admin_sync_user 
    where login_name in
    (select login_name from 
    (select login_name from admin_sync_user group by login_name having count(login_name) > 1) as a)
```

Comment: Could you please add sample input and output ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra   

 `insert into admin_sync_user set login_name="kate",id=1;
insert into admin_sync_user set login_name="kate",id=2;
insert into admin_sync_user set login_name="kate",id=3;`

I insert 3 records to table  "admin_sync_user" with the same login_name  and I want to  delete the duplicate record with the same login_name   and reserve only one record with min(id).

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding content in comments , also Add table Structure, Sample Data and Expected Result in your question